# .htaccess - redirect to https except subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, https, wildcard-subdomain

I am trying to configure .htaccess to redirect all "http" to "https" - except subdomains (but still include 'www' and 'static').

Ex:
**http**://abc.com -> **https**://abc.com

**http**://www.abc.com -> **https**://www.abc.com

**http**://static.abc.com -> **https**://static.abc.com

**http**://hello.abc.com -> **http**://hello.abc.com

**http**://hi.abc.com -> **http**://hi.abc.com

**http**://bye.abc.com -> **http**://bye.abc.com
(please note that I am creating random subdomains... thus I can't exclude a given number of subdomains)

I am literally pulling my hair out for hours on this issue.

1,000 thanks for your help!!
Damien

Comment: It might help to include what you've tried and what's going wrong.

Comment: Would probably make more sense to set up a wildcard certificate, so that you _can_ serve these subdomains via HTTPS as well. What’s the point in making anything only “half secure” these days.

Answer (score 0):

This .htaccess should do the job

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PROTOCOL} ^http$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www|static)\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
```

**Explanation**

`RewriteCond %{SERVER_PROTOCOL} ^http$` Condition is met if protocol is `http` (not https)

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www|static)\.` Condition is met if protocol if subdomain is either `www` or `static`

This will redirect

```
http://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com
http://www.example.com?param=value -> https://www.example.com?param=value
http://www.example.com/something -> https://www.example.com/something
http://static.example.com -> https://static.example.com
http://static.example.com?param=value -> https://static.example.com?param=value
http://static.example.com/something -> https://static.example.com/something
```

But won't redirect

```
http://hello.abc.com
http://hi.abc.com
http://foo.abc.com
```

[Demo](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=145939ea-0c5b-59ea-a8c8-1e7771c6b033)